# i can't find css path in magento 2

Tags: magento2

in the styles tab you can see styles applied on that element and right to that respective style sheet name > mouse over the style sheet to see the path

Eg
:pub/static/version1494043315/frontend/Mobac/porto/en_US/Webkul_Marketplace/css/landingpage_one.css

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are getting compiled file. These files are in the pub/static folder. Which is kind of temporary/dynamic file.

If you are searching for the source of the compiled css code, you might want to turn on client side less compilation like described here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

It will affect performance, but when you inspect the element, you should see the location of the less file in your browser instead of the compiled css file.

Probably a module css file located at : 
 \app\code\Namespace\Module\view\frontend\web\css\style.css

Good Luck!!!